# Using unknown number of tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I want to create an activity that can display any number of tabs, without creating an activity for each tab.
Is it possible?
The only way I saw creating tabs included creating an activity for each one.

Comment: this is possible, you just need to define required number of tabs at  runtime and replace the same fragment again and again

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. I have'nt been programming in android for very long. do you have an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as follows ,

1. Extend your activity from ActionBarActivity and add required number of tabs programmatically ,

   ```
   ActionBar.TabListener tabListener;
   mactionBar = getActionBar();
   mactionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

   tabListener=new ActionBar.TabListener() {
       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
           displayTabs(tab.getPosition());
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
           displayTabs(tab.getPosition());
       }
   };

   mactionBar.addTab(mactionBar.newTab().setText(<any text>).setTabListener(tabListener));
   //call the same method for required number of tabs
   ```
2. Call the same fragment for each tab click

   ```
   private void displayTabs(int position)
   {
   Fragment fragment = null;
   switch (position) {
   case 0:
       fragment = new YourFragment();
       break;
   case 1:
       fragment = new YourFragment();
       break;

   // same for required numder of cases


   default:
       break;
   }

   if (fragment != null)
   {
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(<container id>, fragment).commit();
   }
   }
   ```